# Reltool try to start library

Tags: erlang, reltool

I'm building a release with Reltool. When I try to start it with boot file I get error:

```
14:40:49.466 [error] CRASH REPORT Process  with 0 neighbours crashed with reason: {bad_return,{{z_validate,start,[normal,[]]},{'EXIT',{undef,[{z_validate,start,[normal,[]],[]},{application_master,start_it_old,4,[{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,274}]}]}}}}
14:40:49.472 [info] Application z_validate exited with reason: {bad_return,{{z_validate,start,[normal,[]]},{'EXIT',{undef,[{z_validate,start,[normal,[]],[]},{application_master,start_it_old,4,[{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,274}]}]}}}}
```

But z_validate is a library and I don't want to start it. How can I exclude it from boot scripts?

Answer (score 2):

In `reltool.config` define the release like this (notice the `load` app types):

```
{rel, "cmd", "0.1",
 [{kernel, load},
  {stdlib, load},
  {your_app, load}
 ]},
```

Then when booting up that release (e.g. with `./bin/erl`) it will load all applications but will not try to start them.

Answer (score 1):

Your `z_validate.app` file probably contains a line like this:

```
{mod, {z_validate, []}}
```

Remove that, and the application will be treated as a pure library application.